# ExtJS app.json and bootstrap.json file

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

How added my-custom.css file in app.json or bootstrao.json files
app,json

```
{
    "name": "My App",
    "requires": [
    ],
    "id": "166372b1-e416-4921-8ef2-2495765b9d76"
}
```

bootstrap.json

```
/**
 * This file is generated by Sencha Cmd and should NOT be edited. It is a 
 * combination of content from app.json, and all required package's package.json
 * files.  Customizations should be placed in app.json.
 */
{"id":"166372b1-e416-4921-8ef2-2495765b9d76","js":[],"css":[]}
```

Comment: can you re-phrase your question?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're asking about adding CSS files to your application's `app.json` file. Basically, you need to add the following section to `app.json` then run `sencha app build` (which will update bootstrap.json for you).

```
"css": [
    {
        "path": "resources/css/my-styles.css"
    }
],
```

However, a project initialized with Sencha Cmd would've had this section with helpful comments. Take a few minutes to become more familiar with Sencha Cmd and how you can use that to manage your project's files and build process:

http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/4.0.0/#!/guide/command_app_ext42